# When appending dictionaries to a list through for loop, I get only the last dictionary

Tags: list, python-3.x, for-loop, dictionary, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a career search website by going through all the different pages and I keep running into a problem when I try to append the dictionaries into a list using a for loop.  When I execute the code below in Python 3.4, the code will pull all the relevant data from each page into a dictionary (I've checked with print()) and append into "FullJobDetails", but at the end of the for loop I get a list that is full of dictionaries from the last page only.  The number of dictionaries is exactly the same as the number of pages in the list "ListofJobs". "ListofJobs" is a list of html links to each page that I am scrapping.

I just started learning code, so I know that the code below is not in any shape, way, or form the most efficient or best way of doing it.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

```
FullJobDetails = []
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
dictionary = {}

for jobs in ListofJobs:
  browser.get(jobs)
  dictionary["Web Page"] = jobs
  try:
    dictionary["Views"] = browser.find_element_by_class_name('job-viewed-item-count').text
  except NoSuchElementException:
    dictionary["Views"] = 0

  try:
    dictionary['Applicants'] = browser.find_element_by_class_name('job-applied-item-count').text
  except NoSuchElementException:
    dictionary["Applicants"] = 0

  try:
    dictionary["Last Application"] = browser.find_element_by_class_name('last-application-time-digit').text
  except NoSuchElementException:
    dictionary["Last Application"] = "N/A"

  try:
    dictionary["Job Title"] = browser.find_element_by_class_name('title').text
  except NoSuchElementException:
    dictionary["Job Title"] = "N/A"

  try:
    dictionary['Company'] = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/article/section[2]/div/ul/li[4]/span/span').text
  except NoSuchElementException:
    dictionary['Company'] = "Not found"

  try:
    dictionary['Summary'] = browser.find_element_by_class_name('summary').text
  except NoSuchElementException:
    dictionary['Summary'] = "Not found"

  FullJobDetails.append(dictionary)
```

Comment: Hold on. You parse `job.content` with a real HTML parser, and then immediately *unparse* it and search the raw text with regexes?

Comment: Are you sure the code you've shown is what you're running? The issue you describe is exactly what I'd expect if the line `dict = {}` was outside the loop instead of where you show it. (A point unrelated to your issue: Using `dict` as a variable name is a very bad idea. It shadows the name of the builtin `dict` class which can cause very confusing bugs later on.)

Comment: Yes the code that is shown is exactly the same as the one that is running, "indentation" and all.  If it was resetting itself, I'd imagine that there would only be one dictionary in the list (the last one), instead of multiple ones that all correspond to the last dictionary.  Thanks for your suggestion on renaming dict, I will change that to another variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you create only a single dictionary - dicitonaries are mutable objects - the same ditionary is appended over and over to your list, and on each pass of the `for` loop you update its contents. Therefore, atthe end, you will have multple copies of the same dicitonry, all showing the information on the last page fectched.

Just create a new dictionary object for each run of the  `for` loop. That new dictionary will be saved on the list, and the variable name `dictionary` can hold your new object with no conflicts.

```
for jobs in ListofJobs:
  dictionary = {} 
  browser.get(jobs)
  ...
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much for taking the time to answer the question.